# How to determine whether input is empty or enter is pressed

Tags: ruby

I have a task to `puts` an infinite number of `word`, each in one line to array, and when enter is pressed on an empty line, `puts` these words in reverse order. How can I define when enter is pressed or empty line is input?

Code is here:

```
word = []
puts "Enter word"
add = 0
until add == ????
  word.push gets.chomp
  add = word.last
end
puts word.reverse
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I can tell you that it is impossible to `puts` an infinite number of something (in finite time).

Comment: I've mean that number of inserted word aren't limited.

Comment: If the user presses Enter alone, `gets.chomp` will return an empty string (`''`). You can use that as a signal that the user is finished if an empty string is not a valid data entry. If you want the user to be able to enter empty strings as data, the user will have to signify that he/she is finished in some way other than entering an empty string, such as entering a specific word (e.g., "quit").

Comment: You should select an answer if your found any of them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution, with comments.  I didn't see any useful role being played by your `add` variable, so I ignored it.  I also believe in prompting the user regularly so they know the program is still engaged with them, so I moved the user-prompt inside the loop.

```
word = []    # Start with an empty array
# Use loop when the terminating condition isn't known at the beginning
# or end of the repetition, but rather it's determined in the middle
loop do
  print 'Enter word: '       # I like to prompt the user each time.
  response = gets.chomp      # Read the response and clean it up.
  break if response.empty?   # No response?  Time to bail out of the loop!
  word << response           # Still in the loop? Append the response to the array.
end
puts word.reverse     # Now that we're out of the loop, reverse and print
```

You may or may not prefer to use `strip` rather than `chomp`.  Strip would halt if the user input a line of whitespace.

Comment: Your suggested code and explanation are useful, but you haven't answered the OP's question (i.e., the title and interrogative sentence).

Comment: @CarySwoveland And there I was, thinking that's what `break if response.empty?` was doing.

Comment: That may be sufficient, but as the OP is a newbie to Ruby and quite possibly to programming, I think a more direct explanation is called for. I left a comment on the question that indicates what I think is needed,

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is a modified version of your code and it works as requested.

```
word = []
puts "Enter word"
add = 0
while add != -1 
  ans = gets.chomp
  word.push ans
    if ans == ""
      puts word.reverse
      exit
    end
  add += 1
end

puts word.reverse
```

This is another version, using (as you did originally) the **until** loop.

```
word = []
puts "Enter word"
add = 0
until add == Float::INFINITY
  ans = gets.chomp
  word.push ans
    if ans == ""
      puts word.reverse
      exit
    end
  add += 1
end

puts word.reverse
```